# Multidex issue in Android app Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

Whenever it tried to run the app. this message comes up for versions 5.0 and higher and different multidex exceptions come up while I run it on below lollipop versions here is two different error stack trace:

**5.0 and higher stack trace**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

**below 5.0 stack trace**

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView;
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
>   Error:    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
>   Error:    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
>   Error:    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
>   Error:    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>   Error:    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>   Error:    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>   Error:    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView;

**while generating debug build**

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/DiskBasedCache$CountingInputStream;

**here is Gradle file**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'res/raw/tf.properties'
}
}

ext {
supportLibraryVersion = "27.0.1"
constraintLayoutVersion = "1.0.2"
junitVersion = "4.12"
runnerVersion = "1.0.1"
espressoVersion = "3.0.1"
gsonVersion = "2.2.4"

 }

 dependencies {
//implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

//implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gsonVersion"
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.0'
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
 layout:$constraintLayoutVersion"
implementation project(':framework')

implementation files('libs/io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric-classes.jar')
implementation files('libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_answers-classes.jar')
implementation files('libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_beta-classes.jar')
implementation files('libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics- 
 classes.jar')


testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:$runnerVersion"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '27.0.1'
        }
    }
}
}
```